# How can I give stakeholders read-access to the Repos?

Tags: azure-devops

I have clients as stakeholders, and I want to give them read-access to the Repos.

However, I cannot find out how to do this. Whatever I do, they only get access to the Tasks, Sprints, etc. but not to the Repos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:** 
*(Note: The necessary button is very hidden!)*

1. Go to https://dev.azure.com/yourcompany
2. **In the left bottom corner, click on"Organization Settings"** (look closely!)
3. Next, click on Users.
4. Right of the user, click the 3 dots and "change access level"

Comment: Good job, thanks for your sharing and please consider [marking your reply as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and that will help other community members to search this useful information more easily, it just a reminder :)

Answer (score 1):

Stakeholders do not get access to repositories for private projects, period.

Refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/get-started-stakeholder?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process#features).

Comment: So how can I give other people access to the repositories?

Comment: But how? I don'T see an option and can't find it in the documentation!

Comment: Google "azure devops assign access level"